# Is there any way to detect localized magnetic field change in a magnetic material or powdered magnetic material?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

Hi I was wondering if there was any way to detect localized magnetic field change within either bulk magnetic material or within like powdered magnetic material. The application we are looking for is active property monitoring of magnetic powders on a laser bed and if we could monitor the powder properties in certain sections affected by heating. Does anyone know if something like this exists?